# PHPExcel - Combo Charts

Tags: charts, phpexcel

I am trying to create a combo chart with a secondary axis. Is this possible through PHPExcel?

I have tried to read a 2007 excel file with combo chart but when I write it, it is saying the file is corrupted and no chart appears.

Comment: It is not yet possible to create a secondary Y-axis for charts using PHPExcel

Comment: It is impossible to say why MS Excel is saying your file is corrupted without you giving any indication of the code that you're using to generate that file.... as a best guess, you've done something wrong in your code